# Datatables save state filtering no longer works when no matching records found

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the latest version of the DataTables jQuery plugin. I have column filtering and column reordering enabled and stateSave set to true. I was able to set up column filtering to save the values entered into the input fields on page reload, even when columns are reordered.

There is just one situation that isn't working. When the column filters **do not return any results** (no matching records) and the **page is reloaded**, filtering does not work as expected:

1. The column filter input fields **no longer display the filter by values**
2. Entering new values into the filter input fields **no longer filters the table**

This is my function to apply column filters:

```
    function fDTApplyColFilters(dtable) {

    //searches column on keypress by column filter data

    var dtHeader = dtable.$('tr').closest('div.dataTables_scroll');

    $('tr:eq(1) th', dtHeader).each(function () {

        $('input', dtHeader).keyup(function () {
            var i = ($(this).parent().index() + ':visible');    //uses parent().index for compatibility with column drag-drop reordering
            if (dtable.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                dtable
                    .column(i)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });

    //reloads column filter search values when returning to saved state filtered datatable

    var state = dtable.state.loaded();

    if (state) {
        dtable.columns().eq(0).each(function (i) {
            var newindex = dtable.colReorder.transpose(i, 'toOriginal');    //get correct index after any column drag-drop reordering
            var colSearch = state.columns[newindex].search;
            var inputField = dtHeader.find('input');


            if (colSearch.search) {
                inputField.eq(i).val(colSearch.search);
            }
        });

        dtable.draw();
    }
}
```

There are no console log errors, and when I add this code to the if(colSearch.search) code section, the console log returns the *exact same saved filter parameters* whether the table is returning records or not:

```
      if (colSearch.search) {
                inputField.eq(i).val(colSearch.search);
                console.log(colSearch.search);
                console.log(i);
            }
```

Everything works great on page reload when the filter returns records in the table. But when there are no records in the table that match the filter, the input fields no longer display the filter values (even though they are still saved and display the same way in the console log, which I cannot understand). And the column filters no longer filter the table on keyup press.

I am attaching a jsbin example:

https://jsbin.com/cofexabupu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Enter a filter value in the name column, then reload the page. If the name exists in the table, the column filter saves the name value. If the name *does not* exist in the column, the column input filter field does not save the value and filtering no longer works on the column, even after using the clear filters button.

I have been searching for awhile but have not been able to find any other questions about this issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help from another forum. Just in case anyone has the same problem as I did, the solution was to select the header in a better way:

```
var dtHeader = dtable.table().header();
```

...instead of

```
var dtHeader = dtable.$('tr').closest('div.dataTables_scroll');
```

And to use the jQuery selector here:

```
var inputField = $(dtHeader).find('input');
```

...instead of

```
var inputField = dtHeader.find('input');
```

Comment: Thank you for posting back your own solution. Glad you found it.